# Setting and getting the system-wide default newline character

Tags: macos

Is there a system-wide way to configure the default newline character? If so, is there a way to query what this character is?

Comment: Where do you want this to be done - in Terminal, a text file or inside some programming language (Java, C#, C++, etc.) ??

Comment: @ReneLarsen: Setting: either Terminal or a text file. Getting: Terminal.

Comment: Here are some options for displaying the line feed character(s): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569997/view-line-endings-in-a-text-file

Comment: @ReneLarsen: I explicitly mentioned *system-wide* in the title as well as in the body of my question to emphasize that I am *not* interested in the settings pertaining to a particular file or application, which is what the post you linked to addresses.

Comment: Well system-wide macOS is using CR, and can not be changed - you can however change the newline character(s) used in various editors to use Unix or Windows/DOS newline character(s). In the link there are some ways to see which character(s) a file has - and then if it is what one want - convert from dos 2 unix or from unix 2 dos (which then changes the newline character(s))

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not any way to configure the newline character system wide.

Modern macOS applications typically use `\n` (Unicode character U+000A) as the line separator.

Applications developed for Classic Mac OS (i.e, Mac OS 9 and earlier) often used `\r` (Unicode U+000D) as a line separator, but this usage is extremely rare nowadays.

A good text editor will let you choose your line break:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity: what text editor did you take the screenshot from?

Comment: This one seems to be from TextWrangler - there is a similar setting in TextMate